# Plus Subscription HELP

Tags: ps4

I have 2 accounts on my ps4. The 1st account is the account that has had the Plus membership. That membership has expired. On that same account I purchased little big planet 3 for free. I created a new 2nd account and do not plan to use the original 1st account anymore. So, of course, my little big planet game has lock on it because of the membership expiring. I am getting a new year membership tomorrow.

My questions are:

Which account should I add the membership too if I no longer plan to use the first account anymore?

Since I bought the game on that first account will it unlock as long as there is a subscription on one of the accounts on that ps4 or will the subscription have to be added to the account I used to purchased the game?

If I do add it back to the first account will I be able to play the game from the new account too?

And if I can will it save my game progress as normal?

Comment: Why can't you just use the first account? The game is tied to that account so you either keep the first account, or buy it again on whatever 2nd account you decide to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your game is bound to 1st account (which originally had PS+). If the game was given to your as a monthly free game, then it will be blocked until you get PS+ for that account or buy this game. But if you paid anything for game, it should be available even without the subscription.

Your progress (saves and achievements) is bound to account that you used when played the game. It's possible that you had your PS4 set as primary for your 1st account, but you actually used 2nd one to play - in that case saves will be available for 2nd account.

I think, that if you are not planning to use 1st account, then it makes no sense to buy any subscription for it. You will lose access to this game, but you won't face similar problem in future when your account will eventually get some additional free games. Be aware, that it's not possible to merge different accounts, so for most users it's better to stick with only one account.